# Excel crashes when referring to PowerPoint slides

Tags: excel, vba, macos, crash, powerpoint

I have Excel VBA code to open and analyse some PowerPoint presentations.

The issue seems to be to do with referring to the slides object. When I try to do something associated with a particular slide, it crashes. For example, the following code, much simplified from my original, crashes every time because of the last `set mySlide = myPres.Slides(1)` line.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
Dim myApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim myPres As Presentation
Dim mySlide As Slide

Set myApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set myPres = myApp.Presentations.Add
Set mySlide = myPres.Slides.Add(Index:=1, Layout:=ppLayoutTitleOnly)
Set mySlide = myPres.Slides.Add(Index:=2, Layout:=ppLayoutTitleOnly)

Set mySlide = myPres.Slides(1)

End Sub
```

It doesn't matter what the slide reference is. Anything involving a specific slide gives the same problem. `Slides.count` works but any specific slide range will crash.

I'm using MacOS High Sierra. My Excel version is 16.16.1

Comment: I’m not familiar with the Powerpoint library, but can you confirm that your Slide variable type is as expected? What happens when you `Dim mySlide As Variant`?

Comment: Seems to be a "local" problem. Code is working for me with no problems on Win 10 and Office 365

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the replies. Chris - no change if I set mySlide as Variant. Storax - yes, that's what I think is happening here. There's nothing wrong with the code, from what I can see - it's really simple stuff, almost identical to a lot of demo code from websites various - I'm going to try it on another Mac today to see if it's my machine, or a general Mac thing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing this from within the Excel VBA editor. That being said, we need to change how you are declaring your objects.

```
Dim myApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim myPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim mySlide As PowerPoint.Slide
```

Technically, the slide & presentation objects live within the PowerPoint Object model so we need to reference that library when we declare them.